# Deleting parts of a big string given a list of indexes

Tags: python

Looks like a simple question, but having a string (huge, coming from a big file),
how to remove parts of the string between a pair of indexes (actually a list of pairs of indexes)

For example `removeByIndex("Text aaa bbb", [(0,1), (5, 9)])` would return
`ext bbb`

The indexes are not overlapping.

It has to be efficient since the content is relatively big (up to a few hundreds of megs)

SUMMARY: so in any case solution seems to involve creating a new string and manually going over the index pair list, and adding the indexes that are not in the list.

Comment: Give an example, show some code.

Comment: is it a legit string(ASCII/UNICODE) or a string of bytes?

Comment: If the data is really big, use a more appropriate data structure, like one that text editors use. (A [rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) for instance.)

Comment: The plural of index is indices

Comment: @gnibbler And the plural of "octopus" is "octopodes" if you're being etymologically pedantic, but "indexes" is an accepted usage just like "octopuses" is, as most dictionaries should tell you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing that your pair (start,end) is not inclusive on end, I'll do this
(I've embedded a scalable test case so you can run some performance tests) :

```
N = 100000
s = ''.join([ chr(c % 26 + ord('a')) for c in range(N) ])

l = [ (26*i,26*i+3) for i in range(N//26) ]

l.sort(lambda x, y : cmp(x[0], y[0]))

ns = []
i = 0
for (start,end) in l:
    ns.append(s[i:start])
    i = end
ns.append(s[end:])
s = ''.join(ns)
```

With N = 100 000 000 (the order of your strings), this script runs under 30s. It's slow but might be bearable. Of course, the right data structure is a rope for this particular problem. So if you need to do lot of runs, you should probably either drop Python or use an appropriate data structure in Python.

Comment: It is that slow because your program is O(N^2) see: http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/ To fix it make `ns = []` and at the end `''.join(ns)`

Comment: In fact, in this case, it doesn't change much. The limiting factor is both the slicing and the concatenation. Improving concatenation does not make up for the slow slicing.

Comment: Yeah involves a bit too much playing with the indexes (keeping the track in the `i` variable), but seems to be necessary

Comment: "If you need to do a lot of runs, you should probably drop Python" - or, you know, use ropes in Python. It's a data structure, they're rarely specific to a language. (Although it might still be a good idea to implement said data structure as a C extension.)

Comment: You're right. In my mind, I was targeting max efficiency for this issue. But I guess rope in Python would be OK too. I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Don't worry about performance until you've shown that it's a bottleneck

```
s = s[:i] + s[j:]
```

If that's not fast enough you can't use Python - or C. You'll have to choose a better datastructure

Comment: Beware, by doing this you break indexes. So the pairs to remove will be invalid after the first deletion.

Comment: @deufeufeu, There's no need to rebuild the string over and over. The pairs of indices should be sorted so you can use a generator expression and `"".join()`

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import izip
def grouped(iterable, n):
            return izip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)
big_str="12345893483104921420948124"
indexes = [2,4,5,7]
# if needed, indexes = sorted(indexes)
indexes.insert(0, 0)
indexes.append(len(big_str))
sm_str=""
for a,b in grouped(indexes,2):
    sm_str=sm_str+big_str[a:b]
```

Answer (score 0):

How fast do you need it to be, try:

```
In [9]: import string

In [10]: import random

In [11]: huge=''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for x in range(10000))

In [12]: len(huge)
Out[12]: 10000

In [13]: not_sohuge=huge[0:5000]+huge[6000:]

In [14]: len(not_sohuge)
Out[14]: 9000
```

Some timings:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'import random; import string; huge="".join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for x in range(10000))'  'not_sohuge=huge[0:5000]+huge[6000:]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.96 usec per loop
```